# Computing Jacobi Symbol without factoring. $\left(\frac{4764}{4987}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-345}{5461}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm supposed to be able to compute the Jacobi Symbols  $\left(\frac{4764}{4987}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-345}{5461}\right)$ without factoring.

I've done a problem similar but it was much more simple because I was able to use the fact that

$\big(\frac{a}{b}\big) \big(\frac{b}{a}\big)= (-1)^{\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{4}}$

To reduce the problem and eventually find the solution.

Unfortunately this is not possible for these two symbols since 4764 is even and -345 is even mod 5461.

I've tried messing with these symbols for so long and have yet to find a viable solution that does not involve factoring.

Thank you for any help.

Edit: Typo

Comment: Take [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294271/357390); also see Wikipedia on [the symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\big(\frac{4764}{4987}\big)=\big (\frac{-223}{4987}\big)$ and $223$ is prime.

Otoh, $\big(\frac {-345}{5461}\big) =\big(\frac {5116}{5461}\big) =\big(\frac {1279}{5461}\big),$ where I extracted two factors of $2.$

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the $\left(\frac{4764}{4987}\right)$ one, but I think you misread the second one it is $\left(\frac{-345}{5461}\right) = \left(\frac{5116}{5461}\right)$

Comment: Idk know how to do that one without factoring, off-hand.   You wrote $354$ later.

Comment: $5461 - 345 = 5116$